# How should I go about providing image previews of sites while using Google's Web Search API?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, image, google-search-api

I'm using Google's Custom Search API to dynamically provide web search results. I very intensely searched the API's docs and could not find anything that states it grants you access to Google's site image previews, which happen to be stored as base64 encodes.

I want to be able to provide image previews for sites for each of the urls that the Google web search API returns. Keep in mind that I do not want these images to be thumbnails, but rather large images. My question is what is the best way to go about doing this, in terms of both efficiency and cost, in both the short and long term.

One option would be to crawl the web and generate and store the images myself. However this is way beyond my technical ability, and plus storing all of these images would be too expensive.

The other option would be to dynamically fetch the images right after Google's API returns the search results. However where/how I fetch the images is another question.

Would there be a low cost way of me generating the images myself? Or would the best solution be to use some sort of site thumbnailing service that does this for me? Would this be fast enough? Would it be too expensive? Would the service provide the image in the correct size for me? If not, how could I change the size of the image?

I'd really appreciate answers that are comprehensive and for any code examples to be in ruby using rails.

Comment: Check out http://webthumb.bluga.net/home and http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3621

Comment: Also, just out of curiosity, what's your end goal here? What will these site screenshots be used for? And do you need to store the images or can they be rendered on the fly, returning asynchronously (like what [Litmus](http://litmus.com/) does with their email previews)?

Comment: Both. I'd like to store the images for caching, but initially I'm going to need to render them on the fly and return them asynchronously

Comment: maybe http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ is more up2date - you'll need to convert to an image though. Rendering was just fine for us (javascript, canvas and all ..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as you pointed out in your question, there are two approaches that I can see to your issue:

1. Use an external service to render and host the images.
2. Render and host the images yourself.

I'm no expert in field, but my Googling has so far only returned services that allow you to generate thumbnails and not full-size screenshots (like the few mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947642/create-a-website-screenshot-thumbnail-server-side)). If there are hosted services out there that will do this for you, I wasn't able to find them easily.

So, that leaves #2. For this, my first instinct was to look for a ruby library that could generate an image from a webpage, which quickly led me to [IMGKit](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit) (there may be others, but this one looked clean and simple). With this library, you can easily pass in a URL and it will use the webkit engine to generate a screenshot of the page for you. From there, I would save it to wherever your assets are stored (like [Amazon S3](https://github.com/marcel/aws-s3)) using a file attachment gem like [Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) or [CarrierWave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/253-carrierwave-file-uploads)). Store your attachment with a field recording the original URL you passed to IMGKit from WSAPI (Web Search API) so that you can compare against it on subsequent searches and use the cached version instead of re-rendering the preview. You can also use the `created_at` field for your attachment model to throw in some "if older than x days, refresh the image" type logic. Lastly, I'd put this all in a background job using something like [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) ([railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/271-resque)) so that the user isn't blocked when waiting for screenshots to render. Pass the array of returned URLs from WSAPI to background workers in resque that will generate the images via IMGKit--saving them to S3 via paperclip/carrierwave, basically. All of these projects are well-documented, and the Railscasts will walk you through the basics of the resque and carrierwave gems.

I haven't crunched the numbers, but you can against hosting the images yourself on [S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/#pricing) versus any other external provider of web thumbnail generation. Of course, doing it yourself gives you full control over how the image looks (quality, format, etc.), whereas most of the services I've come across only offer a small thumbnail, so there's something to be said for that. If you don't cache the images from previous searches, then your costs reduces even further, since you'll always be rendering the images on the fly. However I suspect that this won't scale very well, as you may end up paying a lot more for server power (for IMGKit and image processing) and bandwidth (for external requests to fetch the source HTML for IMGKit). I'd be sure to include some [metrics](http://newrelic.com/) in your project to attach some exact numbers to the kind of requests you're dealing with to help determine what the subsequent costs would be.

Anywho, that would be my high-level approach. I hope it helps some.

Comment: cool thanks! so far I'm doing something very similar to what you've suggested. I am currently using PhantomJS, a Webkit engine with a javascript API, to generate the images in parallel Resque background tasks. However, it's not specifically suited for Rails, so I'm definitely going to look into IMGKit to see if I like it better. I was worried about not being able to use PhantomJS on Heroku, and it seems like the library you suggested would work on it.

Comment: I also was not going to originally store anything except the file path of the stored image on the filesystem, and I was checking if the file existed (`File.exist?("path")`) to see if I should serve it from there. However, this probably wouldn't allow me to perform any logic for updating the cache, which a `created_at` field would help me do. Great idea! I'll do this.

Comment: Oh, and I'm in NY as well  :)

Comment: @neezer IMGKit is giving me trouble when trying to generate the image.

Comment: @Justin Meltzer - Did you install `wkhtmltoimage`? Though it may be that this might not work on Heroku either, as `wkhtmltoimage` is a separate compiled binary. You could fire up a minimal [slice](http://www.slicehost.com/) and host your "image processing" (either IMGKit or PhantomJS) there and communicate to it as an external API from your Heroku app. Also, you might want to update your question to say that you're hosting on Heroku.

Comment: yeah I installed it. This is the problem I'm having: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6515807/permission-denied-running-a-method-from-a-ruby-gem I'm not 100% fixed on Heroku at the moment. Is there a good source for interfacing slicehost with Heroku?

Comment: @Justin Meltzer - Well, there's not much to "interface". I mean, it's just another server. Make a small Rails app on a Slice that just does one thing: image processing. Setup a controller to receive a POST action (so you can fetch the URL from your Google Web API) and return the image (using IMGkit or Phantom.js or whatever you want). Capture the request in your main Rails app on Heroku and do whatever you want with it. Does that make sense?

Comment: I just used IMGKit to generate a JPG of Google's homepage at 50% quality, and it came out to 20k (1024x430), so you can scale up from there, I suppose. You can also run your Rails app locally and store images on your local hard drive, then see how big they are, and figure out S3's pricing from there.

Comment: yeah that's what I did. I'm thinking of using the SaaS provided in the other answer because it's so fast. Amazon offers up to 5TB free of storage for the first year, which is about 5 billion KB. On average, each of my images are 400 KB, so that's about 12.5 million images stored for free for a whole year. That's pretty decent so I think I'll go with that.

Comment: just awarded you the bounty :)

Comment: Thanks! Good luck with your project!

Comment: @neezer : url2png can provide original size screenshots. See [the docs](https://url2png.com/doc/)

Answer (score 1):

Screen shotting web pages reliably is extremely hard to pull off. The main problem is that all the current solutions (khtml2png, CutyCapt, Phantom.js etc) are all based around QT which provides access to an embedded Webkit library. However that webkit build is quite old and with HTML5 and CSS3, most of the effects either don't show, or render incorrectly.

One of my colleagues has used most, if not all, of the current technologies for generating screenshots of web pages for one of his personal projects. He has written an informative post about it [here](http://blog.klektd.com/post/7020203758/screenshots-now-100-more-awesome) about how he now uses a SaaS solution instead of trying to maintain a solution himself.

The TLDR version; he now uses [URL2PNG](http://url2png.com/) to do all his thumbnail and full size screenshots. It isn't free, but he says that it does the job for him. If you don't want to use them, they have a list of their competitors [here](http://url2png.com/alternatives/).

Comment: This is really nice. A bit pricey though :/

Comment: Yeah, I think there's a discount code on the blog post to make it slightly cheaper. In the end it really depends on how much screenshots will mean to your product. For my colleague its a major feature so he's prepared to pay. If it's not that big of a deal then using one of the mentioned current tech's will suffice.

Comment: Please note that PhantomJS already moves away from using stock QtWebKit, expect more bleeding-edge WebKit features coming to it in the future releases.

Comment: Also URL2PNG uses Chromium 11, which is a release from a year ago (hence, soon will be in the "outdated" WebKit category as well, unless the backend gets upgraded).