# Permission denied running a method from a Ruby gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, error-handling, rubygems

I'm using a gem called [IMGKit](https://github.com/csquared/IMGKit) and when I use the gem's `to_img` method in the console I get this error:

```
IMGKit::CommandFailedError: Command failed: /rubyprograms/search --format jpg http://google.com -: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:67:in `exec': Permission denied - /rubyprograms/search (Errno::EACCES)
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:67:in `popen3'
from /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/open3.rb:53:in `fork'
```

I have no clue what's going on.

This is the to_img method:

```
def to_img(format = nil)
  append_stylesheets
  set_format(format)

  result = nil
  stderr_output = nil
  Open3.popen3(*command) do |stdin,stdout,stderr|
    stdin << (@source.to_s) if @source.html?
    stdin.close
    result = stdout.gets(nil)
    result.force_encoding("ASCII-8BIT") if result.respond_to? :force_encoding
    stderr_output = stderr.readlines.join
    stdout.close
    stderr.close
  end
  raise CommandFailedError.new(command.join(' '), stderr_output)  unless result
  return result
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This means the user as which your Ruby program is executed does not have the permissions to read or execute the file at /rubyprograms/search (or possible the /rubyprograms directory itself). Check if the directory and/or file exist and are executable by your user. If doesn't exist then you'll need to install some packages or adjust the path in the gem's configuration. If it exists then maybe you need to change ownership or permissions using chown/chmod.

Comment: the file /rubyprograms/search exists. what permission would I need that I don't currently have?

Comment: Well it should be executable by your user. You can check this by logging in on the server using the account that runs your Rails app and trying to execute the file by typing in /rubyprograms/search